# Project's file browser with folder thumbnails for Windows

Tags: file-management, networking, windows-10, thumbnail

I need to find a tool for a company to be able to view project folders accross the network from Windows clients.

We have an WD My Cloud EX4100 NAS server with a folder that contains numerous projects. Before this we had a laptop with folder.ico / desktop.ini inside every folder and we were able to view in a "gallery" layout all projects with its picture as a thumbnail. We now purchase the NAS and AFAIK Windows folder icon view isn't working in network drives.

So I need a program or a Windows hack to be able to "attach" an icon or a JPG in each folder and be able to browser them in all company's Windows clients.

I thought of Picasa but doesnt seem to work like I need.

Would be great if we can add tags on those folders. But the main goal is to view all folder in a gallery layout. The old Windows XP solution seems OK but I don't know if this is possible in Windows 10 / LAN.

[image: Windows XP folder thumbnails]

**UPDATE**:
I tried out [plex](http://www.plex.tv) which seems to be good for my needs. It's hard to handle other files like PDF or Word documents but just for a photo gallery works great.

[image: plex movies layout]

**UPDATE 2**:
I just found out that plex created a network location of plex media server with my libraries and I now can view in Windows explorer with the thumbnail I choose. Although I can't browse and open files other than photos and videos. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out about [WinCatalog 2015](http://www.wincatalog.com/) which worked great! Thanks a lot for your time.

[image: wincatalog-2015-layout]
<sub>(source: [bitsdujour.com](http://download.bitsdujour.com/software/screenshot/wincatalog-2015-vp8vg.png))</sub>